# Running OS X and Windows simultaneously

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp

**Using Bootcamp is it possible to run OS X and Windows simultaneously such that I can command-tab between the two?**  I've run Windows using Bootcamp a few years ago but at that time a restart was required when switching between OS X and Windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Bootcamp** is designed to allow you to change your operating system while the computer **boots**.

Nothing allows you to swap purely back and forth between operating systems that way. What you *can* do is use software that runs Windows in OS X with hardware virtualization, a huge step up from the software virtual machines of old.

There are three good options: [**Parallels**](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/), [**VMWare Fusion**](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/overview.html), and [**VirtualBox**](http://www.virtualbox.org/), the last of which has the advantage of being free.

If you want more technical details, particularly the ones that drove an edit to improve this answer, read the comments below.

Comment: +1 ironically, I totally forgot about VirtualBox, even though that's the one I use.

Comment: ....Uh... Virtualbox uses the same virtualization techniques as Parallels and VMWare Fusion. I don't know where you got the Idea it didn't. It does let you *turn them off*, if you want, but they are normally enabled. The major speed differences come down to different drivers for the virtual hardware used to interface with the VM.

Comment: @Fake Hmm, someone whose low-level OS knowledge I trust explained to me at some length a couple of weeks ago how they were different. Let me do a bit of research and I'll come back and change my answer if I don't have something solid to point to. Thanks for bringing it up, and no need to start with "....Uh" and such: SO/SA is a fine place to correct someone with facts, I certainly don't mind being wrong now and then. Let's just keep it about supplying the best answers.

Comment: All three virtualization systems listen leverage hardware virtualization extensions (AMD-V/VT-x if you have them), and none of the above use hypervisors.

Comment: There are two definitions of hypervisor ( see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor ). All three virtualization techniques listed above use type-2 hypervisors, and none have the option to run as a type-1.

Comment: To be clear, there are certainly differences between type-1 and type-2 VMs, and that may have been what your friend was talking about. Alternatively, he might have meant Paravirtualization ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paravirtualization ), which I *think* Virtualbox supports, and all the others definitely have.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that VMWare benchmarks similarly to VirtualBox in all areas excepting graphics performance (Which Virtualbox does suck at a bit), so it is definitely not slower. http://www.techairlines.com/2009/09/07/virtualbox-3-0-4-vs-vmware-workstation-6-5-3/ http://www.zdnet.com/blog/perlow/virtualization-smackdown-2-oracle-vm-virtualbox-32-vs-vmware-workstation-71/13020

Comment: I'm satisfied. I re-read up on hypervisors and came to the same conclusion between the article you point to and another, and indeed, they all support hardware virtualization very similarly (Parallels supports extended page tables). I thought that VirtualBox wouldn't run the same Windows install as the one in Boot Camp's partition (if you were using both), but with enough hoop-jumping you can. I saw a lot of benchmarks and they seem to depend a lot on whoever last released a new version, except for graphics where VB isn't great and Parallels is currently in the lead.

Comment: Thanks for pushing me to come up with a better answer! I've edited the answer.

Comment: I have a Mac Pro mid-2012, 24 CPU, 48GB Ram, I have tried VBox, Fusion and Parallels.  Fusion works best on my hardware -- much better than VBox.  OSX ver 10.13.6, Vbox ver 6.1, Fusion ver 11.5.3.  Not sure the Parallels version, I uninstalled it because I just didn't like the user experience.  Fusion has always struggled with video, especially Zoom in a Windows VM.  Upgrading my Mac to a metal-capable video card helped., but it still struggles with Zoom.  Still, Fusion (for me) is noticeably better than VBox.

Answer (score 2):

VMware Fusion has a nice feature in 3.x called Unity that allows Windows applications to run on the Mac desktop without running in a window that also runs Windows.  This means that you could have Word 2010 running with the look and feel of Word 2010 on Windows 7, but as another application Window on your Mac.

Windows must still be booted as a VM - it's just that VMware Fusion hides this.  Applications in Unity mode can be pinned to the dock just like regular Mac OS X applications.  Launching them launches VMware, which boots the VM and then spawns the application.

This is akin to Wine on Linux, except a full VM of Windows is running - no API translations, full Windows fidelity.

You can alt-tab amongst Mac and Windows apps.

See: http://www.tuaw.com/2007/06/06/vmware-fusion-unity/

Comment: Parallels and VirtualBox both offer this 'windowed' mode as well.

Comment: VMware working great on my MacPro. I can run Windows and Linux at the same time as the Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

This is still true.  "Bootcamp", as the name implies, is a way to *boot* into a non-Apple operating system, and your computer can only boot into one operating system at a time.

If you want to use Windows programs side-by-side with Mac programs, you'll need to use a virtualization program like [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/) or [Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/overview.html).