# Can I "peek" my MacOS through VirtualBox while in Windows 10 (Bootcamp)?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, virtualbox

*MacBook Pro 13' Late 2019.*

I have a Windows 10 installed in my external SSD, which I installed and ran via Boot Camp ([Tutorial I've Followed](https://medium.com/@transferx23/install-windows-10-on-an-external-hdd-or-ssd-with-boot-camp-under-macos-catalina-10-15-e0e315f2d48d)). I know that Boot Camp does **not** allow switching between both systems, you have to restart the machine to switch and boot the one you desire. (Ref: [Running OS X and Windows Simultaneously](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14901/running-os-x-and-windows-simultaneously)).

What I want to do is:
While in Windows 10 (BootCamp), launch Virtual Box and run my Macintosh HD virtually, so I can do some simples tasks without having to shut down my Windows boot.

Expected result: I would see through VirtualBox my own MacOS, with my login, my configurations, my files, folders, etc...

Is that possible?

Comment: I do something similar with both Windows and Mac machines (images of hard drives) using VirtualBox on macOS.  I use a raw Vmdk to “link” the image to a drive that VB can use. Never tried it with Bootcamp, however.  You might want to give that a shot

Comment: @Allan A tutorial like this is the way to go? https://medium.com/@transferx23/install-windows-10-on-an-external-hdd-or-ssd-with-boot-camp-under-macos-catalina-10-15-e0e315f2d48d

Comment: I did a cursory look and it seems like a fit.  I (personally) would try it, but currently I don't have a machine I'm willing to install BC on (not a huge fan) to test it out.  Both my MacBook and my iMac are now in "production" mode.

Comment: It would be a whole lot easier to do it the other way round, look at (& even run} Boot Camp from a VM on the Mac. […but not for free]